# Applozic - Ignoring header Application-Key because its value was null

Tags: android, applozic

I am new to Applozic and I am integrating it on an android app. When I logged in on the applozic server, this

[image]

Here is my code on Login

```
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserId(UserID);
        user.setDisplayName(strFullName); 
        user.setEmail(loginEmail); //optional
        user.setAuthenticationTypeId(User.AuthenticationType.APPLOZIC.getValue());
        user.setPassword(loginPass); 
        user.setImageLink("");

        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(user, listener,context);
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
```

Comment: Please add your sample codes

Comment: Is applicationKey added in android manifest ?

Comment: @SunilKumar yes it is.
<meta-data
        android:name="com.applozic.application.key"
        android:value="@string/applozic_application_key" />

Comment: @IvanBarayev I updated my post

Comment: Are you calling logout method somewhere ?while some call is going to server

Comment: I already found the issue. I put all the metadata outside the application bracket. It's all okay now. Thanks Guys!